# Is there way to tell whether macroexpansion will or will not see lexical context?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

When performing row-wise operations in a table (implemented as, say, list of lists), it is convenient to refer to cells by their respective column names. I decided to write a shortcut, so that I don't have to write

```
(elt row 5)
```

and so on, and could write

```
(:col "Relevant Header")
```

instead. Not having much experience with Common Lisp, I wrote a macro

```
(defmacro with-named-columns! (sequence-of-rows-symbol body &key headers)
  (labels
      ((replace-col (form headers row-symbol)
         (if (listp form)
             (if (eql (car form) :col)
                 `(elt ,row-symbol ,(position (cadr form) headers :test #'equal))
                 (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (replace-col x headers row-symbol)) form))
             form)))
    (let ((row (gensym "ROW")))
      `(map 'list
            (lambda (,row) ,(replace-col body headers row))
            ,sequence-of-rows-symbol))))
```

that, albeit imperfect, seems to function well enough:

```
(defparameter *table* '(("h1" "h2") ("foo" "bar") ("" "baz") ("foo" "qux")))

(defparameter *sequence-of-rows* (cdr *table*))

(with-named-columns! *sequence-of-rows*
   (when (equal (:col "h1") "")
     'do-nothing-but-make-a-note)
   :headers ("h1" "h2"))

=> (NIL DO-NOTHING-BUT-MAKE-A-NOTE NIL)
```

It macroexpands the way I intended to:

```
(macroexpand-1
 '(with-named-columns! *sequence-of-rows*
   (when (equal (:col "h1") "")
     'do-nothing-but-make-a-note)
   :headers ("h1" "h2")))

=>
(MAP 'LIST
     (LAMBDA (#1=#:ROW724)
       (WHEN (EQUAL (ELT #1# 0) "") 'DO-NOTHING-BUT-MAKE-A-NOTE))
     *SEQUENCE-OF-ROWS*)
```

So far so good. However, headers are often attached to data, in the form of the first row. For such cases, it's natural to have a separate facility:

```
(defmacro process-rows (symbol-bound-to-table-with-exactly-one-header-row body)
  (let ((symbol-for-sequence-of-rows (gensym "SEQUENCE-OF-ROWS")))
    `(let ((,symbol-for-sequence-of-rows (rest ,symbol-bound-to-table-with-exactly-one-header-row)))
        (with-named-columns! ,symbol-for-sequence-of-rows
          ,body
          :headers ,(first (symbol-value symbol-bound-to-table-with-exactly-one-header-row))))))
```

Which, again, seems to work fine:

```
(process-rows *table*
    (when (equal (:col "h1") "")
      'do-nothing-but-make-a-note))

=> (NIL DO-NOTHING-BUT-MAKE-A-NOTE NIL)
```

Macroexpansion leads to a macro inside a let form, and there seems to be no problem with this

```
(macroexpand-1
 '(process-rows *table*
    (when (equal (:col "h1") "")
      'do-nothing-but-make-a-note)))

=>
(LET ((#1=#:SEQUENCE-OF-ROWS726 (REST *TABLE*)))
  (WITH-NAMED-COLUMNS! #1#
                       (WHEN (EQUAL (:COL "h1") "")
                         'DO-NOTHING-BUT-MAKE-A-NOTE)
                       :HEADERS ("h1" "h2")))
```

Side note: Hopefully, this macroexpansion demonstrates why I found it beneficial to provide explicit lists of headers to `WITH-NAMED-COLUMNS!` while hiding the rest rows in a symbol.

*However*,

```
(let ((table '(("h1" "h2") ("foo" "bar") ("" "baz") ("foo" "qux"))))
  (process-rows table
    (when (equal (:col "h1") "")
      'do-nothing-but-make-a-note)))
```

invokes a debugger (SBCL) with the message “The variable `TABLE` is unbound.” — during the macroexpansion of `PROCESS-ROWS`.

I don't yet understand Common Lisp evaluation process well enough. It seems `PROCESS-ROWS` can't see lexical variable, which issue I heard of. But my other macro

```
(let ((sequence-of-rows '(("foo" "bar") ("" "baz") ("foo" "qux"))))
  (with-named-columns! sequence-of-rows
   (when (equal (:col "h1") "")
     'do-nothing-but-make-a-note)
   :headers ("h1" "h2")))

=> (NIL DO-NOTHING-BUT-MAKE-A-NOTE NIL)
```

evaluates just fine in the body of `LET`. I don't see any difference between these two expansions. Is there a way to see? Also, I wrote a different macro (the one I intended to mostly use instead of writing `LET` forms in top level; as a matter of fact, it was the one macro where the issue manifested itself initially), which macroexpands to

```
(LET ((#1=#:TABLE727 (READ-CSV #2=#P"~/test.csv")))
  (WRITE-CSV
   (PROGN
    (PROCESS-ROWS #1#
                  (WHEN (EQUAL (:COL "h1") "")
                    'DO-NOTHING-BUT-MAKE-A-NOTE))
    #1#)
   :STREAM #2#))
```

which signals the same error on evaluation: “The variable `#:TABLENNN` is unbound.” I'm baffled as to how `PROCESS-ROWS` can't see the variable, since those `#1=` and `#1#` are direct references to the same place (much like in macroexpansion of `PROCESS-ROWS`). Apparently, this doesn't guarantee anything.

If there is a way to ensure lexical capture, how do I do it, and if not — at which point did I step into the land of unspecified behaviour? Or maybe I'm missing something simple?

Comment: Generally speaking, a short focused question will receive better answers than a long rambling one. You might want to consider splitting your question into several separate ones.

Comment: I know. The question as posed in the title probably has one correct answer. I am interested in the explanation of discrepancy in two macroexpansions, rather than in solutions to the initial problem. If someone can write a pair of more concise forms that demonstrate the same behavior as the pair in question, all the better. (I can't yet.)

Comment: I suggest that you try my approach (see the answer) yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First mistake**

It's a typical mistake to use macros like that. Just write it in functional style - it will be much easier.

**Second mistake**

```
(defmacro with-named-columns! (sequence-of-rows-symbol body &key headers)
  (labels
      ((replace-col (form headers row-symbol)
         (if (listp form)
             (if (eql (car form) :col)
                 `(elt ,row-symbol ,(position (cadr form) headers :test #'equal))
                 (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (replace-col x headers row-symbol)) form))
             form)))
    (let ((row (gensym "ROW")))
      `(map 'list
            (lambda (,row) ,(replace-col body headers row))
            ,sequence-of-rows-symbol))))
```

You can't just walk over the code tree and replace stuff like that. The tree walk you implemented fully disrespects Lisp syntax. One would need a code walker, which actually understands Lisp syntax. Alternatively use something like `macrolet` or `flet` (mentioned by user sds).

**The bug: the binding may not exist, so you can't access it**

```
(defmacro process-rows (symbol-bound-to-table-with-exactly-one-header-row body)
  (let ((symbol-for-sequence-of-rows (gensym "SEQUENCE-OF-ROWS")))
    `(let ((,symbol-for-sequence-of-rows (rest ,symbol-bound-to-table-with-exactly-one-header-row)))
        (with-named-columns! ,symbol-for-sequence-of-rows
          ,body
          :headers ,(first (symbol-value symbol-bound-to-table-with-exactly-one-header-row))))))
```

What is the *symbol value* of `*table*` at *compile time*? At *macro expansion time*?

What is the *symbol value* of `table` at *compile time*? At *macro expansion time*? Note that the `LET` has not been executed if you compile the code and that `symbol-value` has no access to non-existent lexical bindings. `symbol-value` actually has no access to lexical bindings at all.

Note: the call to `SYMBOL-VALUE`is run by the macro at *macro expansion time* because you have a comma in front of the sub-expression of the backquoted form.

You simply can't or should not use use runtime values during macro expansion. Thus when you write and use macros, you need to pass the actual data so that it is know at macro-expansion time.

Alternatives:

1. provide the data at *macro expansion time*
2. evaluate the source code when that data is available, maybe even at runtime
3. rewrite it as a bunch of functions which take the necessary information as arguments at runtime

Summary: **A lexical binding is not a value of a symbol. A dynamic binding may not exist.**

Comment: Thanks. Is my following summary correct? 1) I try to evaluate top-level `LET` form; 2) SBCL immediately attempts to compile it because that's how SBCL works; 3) prior to compilation, `PROCESS-ROWS` expands; 4) it expands with empty lexical environment, which contains no `TABLE`. I can't figure what happens next, from CLHS. But CLtL2 5.1.2 paragraph 2 would imply that the symbol `TABLE` is then taken to refer to the dynamic variable, which is what happens in my case (I did check this). So, then 5) variable `TABLE` is found unbound; 6) corresponding error is signalled.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on where to read about when different forms are evaluated in a macro?

Comment: @clintm: On Lisp from Paul Graham has a good treatment of macros. Available here as PDF: http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html or buy a printed version. A classic.

Answer (score 2):

## Your specific question

I think your problem is a relatively common one, and it is usually solved  by making your "low-level macro" (`with-named-columns!`) into a *function* which returns the macro-expansion when calling it explicitly from the "high-level macro" (`process-rows`). Cf. [`ensure-generic-function`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ensure.htm) vs [`defgeneric`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defgen.htm).

## Your actual problem

I would like to suggest that you try using [`macrolet` or `flet`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_flet_.htm) and actually defining local functions or macros (e.g., `(h1)`) instead of your not-very-lispy syntax `(:col "h1")`.